# Proof of the existence and uniqueness of Geodesics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, geodesic

Hello fellow mathematicians

i am looking for the proof of existence and uniqueness of geodesics in a random differential manifold. I know that this can be demostrated using Differential equations Theory.

Summarizing, we have the following System of differential equations:

$$\ddot{x}^i+\Gamma _{nm}^{i}\dot{x}^n\dot{x}^m=0,$$

where $x^i$ is the composition of the curve with the i-component of the local coordinate system. This can be simplifice as

$$\dot{v}^i+\Gamma _{nm}^{i}(x)v^nv^m=0,$$
$$\dot{x}^i=v^i.$$
I know that we have to apply Picard-Lindelöf Theorem of existence and uniqueness. Nevertheless, i dont find any source where the proof is developed in detail.

I'm more interesting in the proof of the Lipschitz's condition, i supose that we have to use the properties of Christoffel symbols.

I would need some details of the demostration or any source where i could read the complete proof.

thanks in advance.

Comment: All the functions are smooth, so they are locally Lipschitz.

Comment: Your "simplification" doesn't make sense: the zeroth order term can't be eliminated completely, since the Christoffel symbols depend implicitly on $x$ in general. The correct order reduction would be to introduce auxiliary variables $v^i$ and write$$\begin{align}\dot{v}^i&=-\Gamma^{i}{}_{jk}(x)v^jv^k\\\dot{x}^i&=v^i\end{align}$$

Comment: @Kajelad you're right. I will correct the mistake.Thanks

Comment: I suppose that the argument of @peek-a-boo keep being valid. Since they are smooth, thay are locally lipschitz and applying Picard-Lindelöf theorem, we show that locally, the geodesic exist